# Why is Gedit set as default calendar app in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, gedit, system-settings, calendar

Just wondering why is a text editor (Gvim or Gedit) set as the default calendar app in Ubuntu.

Does any one know the reason why?

[image: system-settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is no real calendar application on your system, it automatically switches to gedit.Because gedit can be configured to have some basic functionality of calendar with extra plugins.

And look here. A bug has been reported on this issue:

[A bug on gedit in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/841409)

Answer (score 1):

There's the ability for you to change it.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install orage
```

From Synaptic:

a calendar for the Xfce4 desktop environment.
It integrates itself nicely into the desktop environment, is highly
configurable and supports alerts based on dates. If you are looking
for a good graphical calendar, you will probably want to try out
orage. It stores its data in iCal format.

[image]

You can find yourself lots of others with preview how do they look like just google it.

e.g. [here](http://www.ekoob.com/best-calendar-applications-for-ubuntu-10427/) or [here](http://lifehacker.com/5882005/the-best-calendar-app-for-linux)

Alternatively,

You can launch Ubuntu Software Center and just type **calendar** in search field and pick one of your choice.

**Edit**

There's also a fix you can apply manually:

```
gedit /home/yourname/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

and paste this line `text/calendar=thunderbird.desktop` at the end of [default applications] save and close it. Now you can run:

```
gvfs-mime --query text/calendar
```

And you'll get e.g.:

```
Default application for 'text/calendar': thunderbird.desktop
Registered applications:
        thunderbird.desktop
```