# How to set gnome calendar by default

Tags: 20.04, default-programs, gnome-calendar

I have the GNOME calendar installed and it works fine.

But there is a problem, it is not the default calendar and I can not select it. In the calendars category, only a text editor is available (apparently by mistake).

I am sure that this is a bug, and really look forward to fixing it in Ubuntu. In the meantime, I hope that someone will tell me how to fix this manually.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Why is Gedit set as default calendar app in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607781/why-is-gedit-set-as-default-calendar-app-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of gnome. Already fixed in gnome 40 and Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 12):

An even easier solution would be to set the value with `gio` itself. Thus,
set with the command:

```
gio mime text/calendar org.gnome.Calendar.desktop
```

Then check what you just did with the following command:

```
gio mime text/calendar
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 21.04. The `mimeapps.list` solution did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
gedit /home/yourname/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

paste `text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop` at the end of `[default applications]` and save.

by querying `gvfs-mime --query text/calendar`

you should get

```
Default application for 'text/calendar': org.gnome.Calendar.desktop
Registered applications:
        org.gnome.Calendar.desktop
```

Comment: `gvfs-mime --query text/calendar` has been replaced by `gio mime text/calendar` in 20.04.

Comment: also `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` is deprecated and `~/.config/mimeapps.list` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

Open Terminal:

```
locate mimeapps.list
```

Find the path starting with home:
/home/user_name/.config/mimeapps.list

Then run the below commands.

```
vim /home/user_name/.config/mimeapps.list
```

or

```
gedit /home/user_name/.config/mimeapps.list
```

*(both vim and gedit allow you to edit text files)*

paste **text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop** under the last application in the default application list

[image]

Save the file and run the below command:

```
gio mime text/calendar
```

Note the following
[image]

And lastly check your default applications under the Ubuntu settings:
[image]