# Text editor default Calendar and cannot be changed in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, default-programs, gnome-calendar

I have Gnome Calendar installed on Ubuntu 20.04.
When I go to default applications under settings, I can not set Gnome Calendar as the default application.  Text editor is the only option that I can select.
Is there any way to make Gnome Calendar the default?

The solution here seems deprecated in Ubuntu 20.04 and no longer applicable
[How to set gnome calendar by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232010/how-to-set-gnome-calendar-by-default)

Comment: The link you provided works, but the `gvfs-mime --query text/calendar` has been replaced with `gio mime text/calendar`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, when I enter: gedit /home/yourname/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list; the file is blank/empty.  Even if I add: text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop and save the file, the default application for Calendar does not update/change in Gnome Settings after entering: gio mime text/calendar.   

Also, just to clarify, yes I swapped out 'yourname' above in favor of the correct login/foldre name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gedit /home/yourname/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

Abbreviated file:

```
[Default Applications]
text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop

[Added Associations]
```

Full file:

```
[Default Applications]
application/x-deb=gdebi.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop
application/x-mimearchive=firefox.desktop
application/x-ms-dos-executable=wine.desktop
application/x-shellscript=gedit.desktop
text/xml=firefox.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop
image/webp=google-chrome.desktop
application/xml=firefox.desktop
application/rss+xml=firefox.desktop
application/rdf+xml=firefox.desktop
image/gif=firefox.desktop
image/jpeg=eog.desktop
image/png=eog.desktop
video/webm=firefox.desktop
application/x-xpinstall=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/enpass=Enpass.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop

[Added Associations]
application/x-deb=gdebi.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;
text/html=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop;
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop;
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop;
application/x-mimearchive=firefox.desktop;
application/x-ms-dos-executable=ghex.desktop;wine.desktop;
x-content/image-dcf=rhythmbox.desktop;
application/x-executable=ghex.desktop;
application/x-shellscript=gedit.desktop;
application/pdf=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop;
image/webp=google-chrome.desktop;
application/xml=firefox.desktop;
application/rss+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/rdf+xml=firefox.desktop;
image/gif=firefox.desktop;
image/jpeg=firefox.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/png=firefox.desktop;eog.desktop;
video/webm=firefox.desktop;
application/x-xpinstall=firefox.desktop;
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
```

`gio mime text/calendar`

Comment: This actually resolved the issue.  Thank you for elaborating, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.

Edit the desktop file and add a line MimeType=whatever in it.

Run `update-desktop-database` Or `sudo update-desktop-database` depending on if the file is in user folders or system folders.