# How to add direclty events( reminders ) in ubuntu 20.04 Calander

Tags: calendar, ux

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu I found a calendar in top of the screen but it's cannot use for add events it's just shows  the date, for me it's very bad UX.But I found another separate app called calendar which I need to open separately,I really don't like to open another calendar app to add my events instead of big bold calendar in top of my screen, Do I have any option ?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Who said you had to open both? I do not understand your problem or question.

Comment: Hi @David may be I don't know how to add events from calendar can you tell me. I simply want is add events from this top corner calendar , I tried but didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text editor default Calendar and cannot be changed in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249968/text-editor-default-calendar-and-cannot-be-changed-in-ubuntu-20-04)